# Commutativity and symmetry of equalities

Tags: arithmetic, symmetry

Is there any mathematical context, useful or not, in which a=b does not imply b=a? If yes and if it is useful please explain how.

Comment: Equality is an [equivalence relation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation), so symmetric